# Is there a standard docstring format to show what signature is expected for an argument that takes a function?

Tags: python, docstring

My `__init__` method accepts another function as an argument called `func_convert`:

```
class Adc:
    """Reads data from ADC

    """
    def __init__(self, func_convert):
        """Setup the ADC

        Parameters
        ----------
        func_convert : [???]
            user-supplied conversion function
        """
        self._func_convert = func_convert

    def read(self):        
        data = 0 #some fake data
        return self._func_convert(data)
```

The argument `func_convert` allows a custom scaling function to be supplied once at instantiation that gets called to convert the data each time it's read.  The function must accept a single int argument and return a single float.  One possible example would be:

```
def adc_to_volts(value):
    return value * 3.0 / 2**16 - 1.5

adc = Adc(adc_to_volts)
volts = adc.read()
```

Is there a standard way to document what the expected signature of `func_convert` is in the parameters section of the `__init__` docstring?  If it makes a difference, I'm using numpy docstring style (I think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this standard exists for docstrings - you can of course explain what the function needs in simple sentences, but I assume you want a standard, documentation generator-friendly way to do this.

If you don't mind switching tools, this is possible using type hints and the `Callable` object from the [typing module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#callable):

```
from typing import Callable

class Adc:
    """
    Reads data from ADC

    """
    def __init__(self, func_convert: Callable[[int], float]) -> None:
        self._func_convert = func_convert

    def read(self):        
        data = 0  # some fake data
        return self._func_convert(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to follow numpy docstring style, there are some examples from numpy which show how function parameters are described:

1)

```
apply_along_axis(func1d, axis, arr, *args, **kwargs)
    ...

    Parameters
    ----------
    func1d : function (M,) -> (Nj...)
        This function should accept 1-D arrays. It is applied to 1-D
        slices of `arr` along the specified axis.
```

2)

```
apply_over_axes(func, a, axes)
    ...

    Parameters
    ----------
    func : function
        This function must take two arguments, `func(a, axis)`.
```

3)

```
set_string_function(f, repr=True)
    ...

    Parameters
    ----------
    f : function or None
        Function to be used to pretty print arrays. The function should expect
        a single array argument and return a string of the representation of
        the array. If None, the function is reset to the default NumPy function
        to print arrays.
```

TLDR: they are described manually, without any special syntax or guidelines. If your goal is to create docstrings similar to numpy's, you can describe them in any way you want. But I strongly suggest following [@jfaccioni answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56382566/9609843) and using type hints.

Comment: I think the `Callable` solution is safest bet, but your snippets were also very helpful!  Based off the first one, I decided to do something like this in the docstring `func_convert : function(int) -> (float)`.  If I could accept two answers, I would!